# How to create necessary pojo classes to send nested json data

Tags: android, json, android-studio, retrofit

I need to send following json request from android app. im using retrofit 2. How to create a pojo class to send this kind of json request?

```
{
    "json_data": {
        "firstname": "fname",
        "lastname": "lname",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "telephone": "0123456789",
        "salutation": "Mr.",
        "dob": "1997/08/15",
        "password":"123456"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are asking how to make a POJO from JSON

You can try using JSON to java converter here https://codebeautify.org/json-to-java-converter
Just Paste your JSON template and hit convert, You will have POJO class with all the getters and setter.

There is also an inbuilt plugin you can use.
try this  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo

Comment: Be careful though, because these automatic creators assume the type of a field by the value, given in the example JSON. It should be fine with yours, but if you had e.g. a "number":42 field, it would assume an integer field, although in a different response, number might be a float.

Comment: Yes, We have to adjust a few things like the Class name and nested JSON array will be another inner class. Code Beautify will convert all Number values to a float type to avoid Typecasting issues even the actual type is int or double there will be no problem running them but we have to handle them. This tool comes handy for the Boilerplate code.

Comment: if you want an inbuilt plugin, try this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo

Answer (score 0):

Try inbuilt plugins to convert json to POJO class like this

1. Go to android studio settings
2. Go to Plugin section
3. Install this plugin for java

[image]

[image]

4. Install this plugin for kotlin

[image]

4. Copy json
5. Click on package in which you want to create class
6. Click on new then choose json to POJO like this

[image]

Comment: im using java, not kotlin. is there any add ons for java?

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("json_data")
    @Expose
    private JsonData jsonData;

    public JsonData getJsonData() {
        return jsonData;
    }

    public void setJsonData(JsonData jsonData) {
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
    }

}
```

---

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class JsonData {

    @SerializedName("firstname")
    @Expose
    private String firstname;
    @SerializedName("lastname")
    @Expose
    private String lastname;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("telephone")
    @Expose
    private String telephone;
    @SerializedName("salutation")
    @Expose
    private String salutation;
    @SerializedName("dob")
    @Expose
    private String dob;
    @SerializedName("password")
    @Expose
    private String password;

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }

    public void setSalutation(String salutation) {
        this.salutation = salutation;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

---

[this site create these for you](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following way, your left side fields should the variable name in POJO.

Java :

```
class Data {
   public String firstname;
   public String lastname;
   public String email;
   public String telephonies;
   public String salutation;
   public String dob;
   public String password;
}

class Request{
     Data json_data;
}
```